# Any better sotware for Mouse Keys then the default Universal Access?

Tags: keyboard, mouse, accessibility, navigation

At times I want to use my external keyboard, but don't have my external mouse around or it's death with batteries, which is the time I wish to navigate my cursor with the keys of my keyboard.
So I go with this:

[image: Turning on the Mouse Keys]

But the navigation is utterly and unusably slow. Even if I put my mouse/touchpad speed to max, it's hardly usable.  Is there any hidden .config file to fix, or other software for that kind of functionality?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, that sounds like quite a promising option..!  How'd I do that?

Comment: Yes, my external keyboard is with the numeric block, which I'd like to use for the cursor/pointer navigation.

Comment: @JacobVlijm : Any success in such a creative attempt?