# How can I make shortcut keys move the mouse, as an alternative to the touchpad?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, scripts, mouse

Due to large quantities of Chocolate Cake falling on my computer's touchpad it has become unresponsive at times (though the left- and right-click works fine) and I would like to make it so that when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and at the same time hold down one or two of the arrow keys for the mouse to move accordingly. So if the <kbd>up-arrow</kbd> key is pressed it will move up, if the <kbd>left-arrow</kbd> key, then left, and so, and if the <kbd>right-arrow</kbd> key and the <kbd>top-arrow</kbd> keys are being help down together for it to move diagonally (and so on for the rest of the keys).

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18, can this be done? And if so how? I would accept a script which does this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Scripted alternative to Universal access (to move the mouse)

Not 100% exactly like you describe, nevertheless an alternative for using the mouse or touchpad. The answer below in fact is an almost exact copy of an answer I posted a long time ago on [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/585708/any-better-sotware-for-mouse-keys-then-the-default-universal-access/586521#586521). I deleted it however, since I never had the chance to find out if it was what OP was looking for (no response *at all*).

In your case, since you only want to use it to *move* the mouse, you can leave out a number of shortcut keys (the last three) which will also prevent the most "risky" options. The *scripted* options should work fine any way, without risks on conflicting situations.

#### Mouse Keys alternative

As mentioned, the script offers basic mouse functionality, as an alternative to the default Mouse Keys- option in *System Settings > Universal Access*. Unlike Mouse Keys, the mouse pointer is moved (either x- or y wise) by *repeated clicks*, in two modes:

- bigger steps (as it is set now: 50px)
- smaller steps to "finish" (as it is set now: 3 px)

To my own surprise, I found it reasonably comfortable to use. It is definitely not the same level as a "real" mouse, but (much) more comfortable than the use of Mouse Keys, at least in my experience. After five minutes to get used to it, I was able to perform practically all "normal" actions; opening applications, drag windows, edit text etc.

#### Disadvantage

There is however a downside to mention:

Unlike Mouse Keys, the setup does not "claim" the NumPad exclusively. The disadvantage of that is that there is a bigger chance of key clashes, especially with the left/right click and hold the left click -functionality. Although I did not run into insurmountable situations, you might run into some conflicts, and being familiar with general shortcut keys is an advantage.
You will have to try and see if it works for you.

#### The setup

1. The script needs xdotool:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xdotool
   ```
2. *Disable* mouse keys (most likely it already is)
3. Copy the script below into an empty file, save it as `mouse`(no extension) in `~/bin` (create the directory if needed).

   ```py
   #!/usr/bin/env python3
   import subprocess
   import sys
   #--- Don't change these lines:
   direction = sys.argv[1]
   speed = sys.argv[2]
   #--- Change the steps below if you'd like to
   big_step = 50
   small_step = 3
   #---

   step = big_step if speed == "fast" else small_step
   step = -step if direction == "left" or direction == "up" else step
   get = lambda cmd: subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode("utf-8")

   def move():
       coords = [int(it.split(":")[1]) for it in get(["xdotool", "getmouselocation"]).split()[:2]]
       if direction in ["left", "right"]:
           cmd = "xdotool", "mousemove", str(coords[0]+step), str(coords[1])
       elif direction in ["up", "down"]:
           cmd = "xdotool", "mousemove", str(coords[0]), str(coords[1]+step)
       subprocess.call(cmd)
   move()
   ```
4. Make the script executable.
5. If you just created `~/bin`, either log out/in, or run `source ~/.profile`, to make the directory "visible" in `$PATH`.
6. Now add a number of shortcut keys. All shortcut keys as I set it up are aiming on the use of the NumPad, in combination with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (fast move), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (slow move, mouse left click), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>, (right click, mouse down).

   Add the following shortcut keys: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the commands (11 in total, including mouse keys):

   ```
   mouse left fast
   ```

   key combination: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Num Left</kbd>

   ```
   mouse right fast
   ```

   key combination: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Num Right</kbd>

   ```
   mouse up fast
   ```

   key combination: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Num Up</kbd>

   ```
   mouse down fast
   ```

   key combination: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Num Down</kbd>

   And:

   ```
   mouse left slow
   ```

   key combination: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Num Left</kbd>

   ```
   mouse right slow
   ```

   key combination: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Num Right</kbd>

   ```
   mouse up slow
   ```

   key combination: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Num Up</kbd>

   ```
   mouse down slow
   ```

   key combination: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Num Down</kbd>

   Additionally, I set shortcut keys for:

   - left-click:

     ```
     xdotool click 1
     ```

   key combination: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>*</kbd>

   - right-click:

     ```
     xdotool click 3
     ```

   key combination: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>*</kbd>)

   - hold left click (e.g. to grab, use click to release):

     ```
     xdotool mousedown 1
     ```

   key combination: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>)

Comment: So as I understand it, you have to do repeated clicks and can't just hold down a key and have it move smoothly and constantly in that direction until the key is released?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure if I fully understand, what exactly are these "Mouse Keys" to which you keep on referring to?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda That's true, but you can do it in two steps. In "those days" I tried to work with it a day or two. It worked remarkably well.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda Ah, I could remove that, it refers to the system settings "mouse keys", which is dreadfully slow. You need a week or so to get from one side of the screen to the other.

Comment: Ok, well I'm sure I'll get used to it! Also, about these "Mouse Keys", I can't actually find them in System Settings... But maybe it is different on GNOME? Anyway, I don't need them now that I've got your script! Thanks! :)

Comment: @ParanoidPanda on Unity, it is in System Settings > Universal Access > Mouse